# is php configuration option --with-openssl needed?

Tags: php, configuration, openssl

Does making php 4.4.9
`./configure --with-openssl`
is necesary to enable ssl, cause when i enable ssl on Apache2 its seems to be working ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you want.

If you just want your project to work through `https` - then only your webserver should support ssl.

If you want to work with certificates, verify/encrypt/decrypt in php - you need to add support to php too.